# encrypt data in javascript and decrypt in php

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome-extension

I have browser extension which is developed by using crossrider. From this extension i need to send some data's into the server. But before sending the data i need to encrypt and send it to the server.  I need to decrypt this data on server side and store into the database. I have tried with Cryptojs encrypt and decrypt method to achieve this. But there is some issues with decryption is that sometimes the decryption result getting null. Sometimes it's getting the exact result. I am not sure why it's returns a null result to the extension. 
When using the postman REST API client the result is getting exactly. The null value return issue is with extension only.

extension.js

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
appAPI.resources.includeJS('aes.js');
appAPI.resources.includeJS('jquery.js');
appAPI.resources.includeJS('aes-json-format.js');


$(document).on('click','#submit', function() {

    var word = $('#val').val();
    var passphrase = "EncryptionKey";
    var encrypt_message = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(word), passphrase, {format: CryptoJSAesJson}).toString();
    $('#client_result').val(encrypt_message);
    appAPI.message.toBackground({action:"encrypt",word:encrypt_message});
});


appAPI.message.addListener(function(msg) {
    switch(msg.action) {
        case 'server_result':
                 $('#server_result').val(msg.result);
            break;
    } //end switch
}); //end listener

});
```

background.js

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {

appAPI.openURL({ resourcePath: "test.html", where: "tab"});

appAPI.message.addListener(function(msg) {


    switch (msg.action) {

        case "encrypt":
                       var u="URL to the server";
                       var data = {message:msg.word};

                       appAPI.request.post({
                            url:u,postData:data,
                            onSuccess:function(res){
                                try{
                                    var datas=jQuery.parseJSON(res);
                                    alert(datas.result);
                                    appAPI.message.toActiveTab({
                                        action      : 'server_result',
                                        result      : datas.result
                                    });



                                }catch(err) {
                                    alert("JSON parsing Failed"+err);
                                }
                            },
                            onFailure:function(httpCode) {
                                alert("failure: " + httpCode);
                            },
                            contentType:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    }); //end request post

            break;

    } 
}); 

});
```

To get the javascript and PHP libary please check the following link :https://github.com/brainfoolong/cryptojs-aes-php
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using to accomplish this?

Comment: @StigPerez i have modified the question